# When using get_categories or similar, is it possible to filter results that contain certain Tags as well?

Tags: categories, tags

`get_categories()` and related functions, by default, don't return empty categories - categories with no posts.

I thought that, since there may be some underlying code checking the post counts, is it possible to additionally filter that list to only include categories *that themselves* contain posts that have a certain, specific Tag associated?

Or is there a somewhat simple alternate method of getting that information?

For example, if I had some posts with a Tag of "audio", I'd like a way to use `get_categories()` (or similar results) but only retrieve a list of categories that contained posts with that "audio" Tag.

I am aware that I may have to use the Tag ID directly. I'm just looking for the "best", or most appropriate way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my answer on [how to get terms that are associated with others through the posts that they're attached to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/show-certain-terms-from-custom-taxonomy-but-exclude-parent-terms/16795#16795).

In your case, you could put it into practice like so;

```
$category_IDs = get_terms_soft_associated( 'category', array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => 'audio'
) );

wp_list_categories( array( 'include' => $category_IDs ) );
```

Or for a more general-purpose approach, use a function;

```
/**
 * List categories for posts that have $tag.
 * 
 * @param string|int|object $tag Tag slug, ID or object
 * @param string|array $args Args to pass to {@see wp_list_categories()}
 * @return string
 */
function list_categories_with_tag( $tag, $args = '' )
{   
    if ( is_object( $tag ) )
        $tag = ( int ) $tag->term_id;

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
    $args['include'] = get_terms_soft_associated( 'category', array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field'    => is_numeric( $tag ) ? 'term_id' : 'slug',
        'terms'    => $tag
    ) );

    return wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin for an idea.