# get / list categories and counts filtered by custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, categories

In my post 'post type' besides "categories" I've a custom taxonomy called "product-types".
The category is actually more "manufactures" of the product types.

I've a product-types page where I list all products which has the selected product-type.

In my sidebar, I want a list showing all available manufactures under that prouduct-type, as an extra filtering function.

Example:

My product-type term 'SUV' has 'posts' ML320, X6, ASX, Outlander.
These are respectively categorised with the manufactura category: 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsubishi'

I want a sidebar on my 'SUV' page which says something like:

**Manufactura**:

- Mercedes (1)
- BMW (1)
- Mitsubishi (2)

However, I've tried a bunch of things, among others these two answers https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20359/6751 & https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16795/6751 but I haven't manage to get it to work.

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Yo yo yo, my ears are burning. The fact you need post counts for each term completely changes the game. You have any idea how many posts you might end up with? We talking 1000's or 100'000's? We're looking at some intensive querying here.